# Laravel 4.2 Pagination not working

Tags: php, laravel, comments, forum, pagination

I'm having some issues with my pagination, I'm trying to paginate my comments on a forum section I'm making. It worked fine for my 'Categories' and 'Threads', but for comments, I can not seem to get my paginations to work at all.

Here's the code that works for threads:

```
public function category($id){
    $category = ForumCategory::find($id);
    if ($category == null){
        return Redirect::route('forum')->with('fail', "That category doesn't exist.");
    }

    $threads = $category->threads()->paginate(10);
    return View::make('forum.category')->with('category', $category)->with('threads', $threads);
}
```

And here's the code that doesn't work for comments:

```
public function thread($id){
    $thread     = ForumThread::find($id);

    if ($thread == null){
        return Redirect::route('forum')->with('fail', "That thread doesn't exist.");
    } 
    $author = $thread->author()->paginate(5)->first();

    return View::make('forum.thread')->with('thread', $thread)->with('author', $author);
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `->first()` after having used the `paginate` function?

Comment: If I don't, I get this error:

Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$avatar (View: D:\websites\laravel_nfgm8\app\views\forum\thread.blade.php)

Unfortunately, the youtube tutorial serie I followed for a forum in laravel 4.2. in the beginning has been deleted, and the only references I got now are from my files from then, so I'm unsure what else to put for it to work :)

Comment: I don't understand why you want to paginate some comments but the relation is called `author`. How does the relation looks like?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to iterate over this paginator in your view? I think something is going wrong there. (in combination with the `first()` in your controller code)

Comment: I guess the relation you're thinking of, is the linking between the database tables of category, threads and comments? that would be this:
    
`<?php

class ForumCategory extends Eloquent{
 protected $table = 'forum_categories';

 public function threads(){
  return $this->hasMany('ForumThread', 'category_id');
 }

 public function comments(){
  return $this->hasMany('ForumComment', 'category_id');
 }

 protected $fillable = array('title', 'text', 'created_by', 'avatar');

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've found a fix for it, which works for me, only thing is I now need to find a way to make it so the thread's primary message (first post is part of forum_threads on database) works together with the pagination of comments, however, the comments themselves get paginated now. The code I used to do so:

```
public function thread($id){
    $thread     = ForumThread::find($id);

    if ($thread == null){
        return Redirect::route('forum')->with('fail', "That thread doesn't exist.");
    } 
    $author = $thread->author()->first();
    $comment = $thread->comments()->paginate(5);

    return View::make('forum.thread')->with('thread', $thread)->with('author', $author)->with('comment', $comment);
}
```